# Regex: match if group is only once in text

Tags: python, regex

I need to match if the second group matches only once in all text.
For example, the 1st, 4th, 6th strings should not be matched:
[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/e31oh3/4/)

```
AS "(.+)\.(.+)"

table1.field1 AS "table1.field1",
table2.field2 AS "table2.field2",
table3.field3 AS "table3.field3",
table4.field1 AS "table4.field1",
table4.field1 AS "table5.field5",
table6.field6 AS "table6.field1",
```

Comment: you would need to add additional logic to achieve this, regex alone is not enough, even a CFG is not enough for this

Answer (score 2):

You could just use your original pattern and then filter the matches:

```
regex = r"\bAS \"(.+)\.(.+)\""
matches = re.findall(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

filtered = [x for x in matches 
            if sum(y[1] == x[1] for y in matches) == 1]
```

**Output:**

```
[('table2', 'field2'), ('table3', 'field3'), ('table5', 'field5')]
```

**[Try it online](https://rextester.com/GKTBM3781)**.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do what you want with PyPi regex module that allows infinite width lookbehind patterns:

```py
AS "([^.]+)\.([^.]+)"(?<!AS "[^.]+\.\2"[\s\S]*AS "\1\.\2")(?![\s\S]*AS "[^.]+\.\2")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5utCzq/1). Details:

- `AS "([^.]+)\.([^.]+)"`:

  - `AS "` - a `AS "` string
  - `([^.]+)` - Group 1: any one or more chars other than `.`
  - `\.` - a `.` char
  - `([^.]+)` - Group 2: any one or more chars other than `.`
  - `"` - a `"` char
- `(?<!AS "[^.]+\.\2"[\s\S]*AS "\1\.\2")` - a negative lookbehind that cancels the match if, immediately to the left of the current position, there is

  - `AS "` - a literal string
  - `[^.]+` - one or more chars other than `.`
  - `\.` - a dot
  - `\2` - same value as in Group 2
  - `"` - a double quote
  - `[\s\S]*`  - 0 or more chars as many as possible
  - `AS "\1\.\2"` - `AS "`, same value as in Group 1, `.`, same value as in Group 2 (it is necessary here to make sure we match the part of string matched with the above consuming pattern part)
- `(?![\s\S]*AS "[^.]+\.\2")` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there are any zero or more chars as many as possible, `AS "`, one or more chars other than `.`, `.`, the same value as in Group 2 and a `"`.

[Python demo](https://tio.run/##ZZDRDoIgFIbveQrkRijHpqZXNdczeCm22aRyI3XEBT09qURU3vF/5xv/zhmf6jb0qTHdfRykgpJfuQaKawUPECGkmrPgMb10XLQxPJbwl6AILDmxOfGGI85IbU694YgzdquW3V/L2sgsyZyR25x7I//8MW0DpJ7WkuE8xdWJ1lvC6PuBcLEP5sESGWUJqtiDlfVmhixeCMFF8EW9SkIwyq5X2F5wKu3bRggsdQTnaxJIjHkB):

```
import regex
text = """table1.field1 AS "table1.field1",
table2.field2 AS "table2.field2",
table3.field3 AS "table3.field3",
table4.field1 AS "table4.field1",
table4.field1 AS "table5.field5",
table6.field6 AS "table6.field1","""
rx = r'AS "([^.]+)\.([^.]+)"(?<!AS "[^.]+\.\2"[\s\S]*AS "\1\.\2")(?![\s\S]*AS "[^.]+\.\2")'
print( regex.findall(rx, text) )
# => [('table2', 'field2'), ('table3', 'field3'), ('table5', 'field5')]
```